# Zendframework 2 ( ZF2 ) Oath library documentation

Tags: php, oauth, zend-framework2

Does anyone knows where to find a documentation of ZF2 Oauth library.I am not sure they have completed this library yet.any clue ?

i found one for ZF1.* http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendOAuth/tree/master/library/ZendOAuth maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is all that I was able to find for you: https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zendoauth.getting-started.html

I hope that helps =)

Comment: Hay Thank Diemuzi,this helps me to get an idea.now i am on a process of writing a ZF2 oauth module on my own.Thanks again for the tip.